# Logic notation explanation analysis

Tags: real-analysis, logic

What would be the difference between the two:

$\exists x\in X$ $:$ $\forall \epsilon>0$  $(|x|<\epsilon \implies x=0)$

and

$\exists x\in X$ $(\forall \epsilon>0$, $|x|<\epsilon$ $\implies x=0$)

?

The reason I ask is because negating the two statements yields different statements (look at comments)

Comment: The second one does not seem to have much sense. What are the statements you get by negating them?

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso the second one you get $\exists x \in X$ ( $\forall \epsilon>0$ , $|x|<\epsilon$ and $x\neq 0$ ) (note: i edited). Consider the real numbers if $|x|<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$ then $x=0$. The negation would be suppose hypothesis holds and conclusion doesnt. Then consider $\epsilon= \frac{|x|}{2}|$...

Comment: It might help if you use a standard syntax: neither is well-formed in any syntax familiar to me.

Comment: @PeterSmith thats the issue, i'm not sure how to phrase in a well formed syntax, consider the above example.

Comment: I guess that the correct way to form this statement is $$(|x|<\epsilon ,\forall \epsilon > 0) \implies x=0 , (\forall x \in X) $$

Comment: I have only seen $(\forall\varepsilon\gt 0)(\forall x\in X)(\vert x\vert\lt\varepsilon\implies x=0)$.

Comment: @Cheesecake how would you negate that statement? $(\exists x\in X)$ $(\exists \epsilon>0)$ ( $|x|<\epsilon$ and $x\neq 0$)? In this case, it wouldn't apply to the above problem then, no?

Comment: use parentheses

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam done.

Comment: Use more (in second statement which is still ambiguous).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that neither of them are well-formed statements. The correct version of what you're trying to write is 
$$(|x|<\epsilon ,\forall \epsilon > 0) \implies x=0 , (\forall x \in X).$$

Comment: sure, what about $(\forall \epsilon>0)$ $(|x|<\epsilon) \implies x=0$ ($\forall x\in X$). How would you interpret that statement?

Comment: The thing is that that statement is not true. The two sentences $(|x|<\epsilon)$ and $\forall \epsilon > 0$ must have an "AND" operator between them. Otherwise the statement just isn't true.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: $(|x|<\epsilon) \implies x=0$ $(\forall x\in X, \forall \epsilon>0)$ where $,$ denotes and operator.

Comment: It keeps being false in general. The condition $\forall \epsilon > 0$ must be part of the hypothesis. The statement isn't true otherwise. What you wrote lets you "use" any $\epsilon$ to come to your conclusion, and that's trivially not true for any $\epsilon >0$. For example, for $\epsilon = 1$, your statements says that $1/2 = 0$, and that's false.

Comment: ahh i see, this discussion helped. Thank you.